# Birt: Webservice returns xml string..how to map to columns?

Tags: xml, web-services, birt

I am using a wsdl/webservice url to connect to a data source. The problem is that this webservice returns an xml string as an output. Now my problem is that I am not able to map this into proper fields/columns. A sample returned xml string is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response><items><item><nv_id>1</nv_id><nv_id_parent>0</nv_id_parent><nv_label>Satisfactory</nv_label></item><item><nv_id>2</nv_id><nv_id_parent>1</nv_id_parent><nv_label>Niveau admin</nv_label></item><item><nv_id>3</nv_id><nv_id_parent>2</nv_id_parent><nv_label>Enseigne</nv_label></item><item><nv_id>4</nv_id><nv_id_parent>3</nv_id_parent><nv_label>Magasin</nv_label></item></items></response>
```

I have found a way to parse the xml and compute columns from it. However, the problem is that the xml string is returned as a single row so only the first row of data is extracted in the computed column. How can I fetch all the rows from the xml dataset?

I have used below code to parse the above xml and create a column.

```
importPackage(Packages.org.apache.xerces.parsers);
importPackage(Packages.org.xml.sax);
importPackage(Packages.java.io);

var parser = new DOMParser();
parser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(dataSetRow["return"])));
var nodelist = parser.getDocument().getElementsByTagName('nv_label');
var entry = nodelist.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

entry;
```

Now the problem is that the xml is returned as a single row string. The xml string contains a lot of rows and I would like to fetch all those rows for the column. How can I do that?

P.S: I am not very good with javascript or java or pojo or scripted data source so please provide a bit more detail if your solution will use any of these

Answer (score 0):

If you use BIRT Designer to design the data source connection you first make the WSDL data source with an endpoint like http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL.

Then you create the data set to retrieve and structure from the data source. Use the data set wizard to map the XML schema to columns.

You can then open the XML of the report to extract the format or immediately start making a report from the data. There are a lot of values that you can set to retrieve the content that you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that the xml is returned as a string from the dataset. for example, have a look at https://plus.google.com/photos/103503173145476304072/photo/6169114988860869970 and https://plus.google.com/photos/103503173145476304072/photo/6169114844774412082. My problem is that after the row is returned as an xml string, how to parse it into rows and columns

Comment: Basically the soap request returns a string that is xml. Now the problem is to convert that returned xml into rows and columns. <message name="listLevelsIn"><part name="key" type="xsd:string"/></message><message name="listLevelsOut"><part name="return" type="soap-enc:Array"/></message>

Comment: Have you considered trying to set it up as an XML data source then?

Comment: but the response is returned as a result of call to wsdl. I tried copying the returned xml string into a file and used it as a datasource and it works. Now the problem is that everytime a different xml is generated based on parameters etc so I want to parse this xml dynamically rather than making it a hardcoded xml file

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that the xml data structure was changing dynamically. If the column names and layout are going to be changing regularly it may be difficult to report on it without using multiple data source configurations. Is there a reason the data source accessible by WSDL is not responding with properly formatted XML? I mean if a WSDL client (BIRT) cannot read the data to a WSDL request it sounds like there are problems at the data level. Have you tried making similar queries with other WSDL clients like SOAPUI?

Comment: I don't think that there is a problem with wsdl. It just designed that it returns a string/array that contains the xml. I think what I need to do is first fetch the xml string from the wsdl and then parse the xml string to fetch rows from it. I think it might be done using a scripted dataset. How that can be done is something I dont have experience with. I might need help with wring the script to parse the xml string and convert them into rows and columns